# composer install ///You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I run the composer install command, I get the following:
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\folder\folder\Desktop\qr
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you disable SSL/TLS protection so try to enable it.
use this command.

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls false
```